# Key Value Pair XML (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sqlxml

I am currently using this:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM SomeTable 
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('KeyValuePairs')
```

to produce this:

```
<KeyValuePairs>
<Column1>ColumValue1</Column1>
<Column2>ColumValue1</Column2>
</KeyValuePairs>
```

is there a way to produce something more descriptive like this:

```
<KeyValuePairs>
<KeyValuePair><Key>Column1</Key><Value>ColumValue1</Value></KeyValuePair>
<KeyValuePair><Key>Column2</Key><Value>ColumValue2</Value></KeyValuePair>
</KeyValuePairs>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT (
       SELECT 'Column1' AS [Key],
              T.Column1 AS Value
       FOR XML PATH('KeyValuePair'), TYPE
       ),
       (
       SELECT 'Column2' AS [Key],
              T.Column2 AS Value
       FOR XML PATH('KeyValuePair'), TYPE
       )
FROM SomeTable AS T
FOR XML PATH('KeyValuePairs')
```

Alternative:

```
SELECT  'Column1' AS [KeyValuePair/Key],
        T.Column1 AS [KeyValuePair/Value],
        NULL,
        'Column2' AS [KeyValuePair/Key],
        T.Column2 AS [KeyValuePair/Value]
FROM SomeTable AS T
FOR XML PATH('KeyValuePairs')
```

Comment: @csetzkorn If you could explain in what way it is wrong I might be able to make it work for you.

Comment: There a two columns hence 2 key value pairs not just one as in your case.

Comment: @csetzkorn I see, updated the answer. Not sure how you want the XML when there are more than one row in `SomeTable`. This will give you a `KeyValuePairs` node for each row in.